# Why adding "print(list(solutions))" change the output of the script?

Tags: python

The following is a solution for 8-queen problem. I added one line to do debug but it changed the output. Could someone tell me what was the reason for that ?
Please try to comment and uncomment "#print(list(solutions))" and you will know what I mean. Thanks,

```
    BOARD_SIZE = 8

    def under_attack(col, queens):
        return col in queens or \
               any(abs(col - x) == len(queens)-i for i,x in enumerate(queens))

   def solve(n):
        solutions = [[]]
        for row in range(n):
            solutions = (solution+[i+1]
                           for solution in solutions # first for clause is evaluated immediately,
                                                     # so "solutions" is correctly captured
                          for i in range(BOARD_SIZE)
                           if not under_attack(i+1, solution))
           #print(list(solutions))

        return list(solutions)

    answers = solve(BOARD_SIZE)
    print(answers)
```

Comment: In some languages -- like Clojure -- your lazy sequences actually cache their results from the beginning, so you can read them more than once. Python is not one of those languages.

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Because `solutions` is a generator, so when you call  `print(list(solutions))` you're exhausting the generator. You would have to assign `list(solutions)` to a variable and then print/return that variable. Or change the generator to a list comprehension. So, for example.

```
   def solve(n):
        solutions = [[]]
        for row in range(n):
            solutions = [solution+[i+1] for solution in solutions for i in range(BOARD_SIZE) if not under_attack(i+1, solution)]
            print(solutions) 

        return solutions
```

I also don't understand `solutions = [[]]`, because you immediately overwrite it.